# How to inject viewModel in base classes like baseActivity or baseFragment using hilt. Android kotlin

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, dagger, inject, dagger-hilt

I tried to inject viewModel to my base activity using hilt

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VB: ViewBinding, VM: BaseViewModel>(val bindingFactory(LayoutInflater) -> VB) : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: VM by viewModels<>()
    lateinit var binding: VB
}
```

but am getting error here on viewModels() function as
"Property delegate must have a 'getValue(BaseActivity , KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable."

how do I inject viewModel in base classes using hilt, or is it possible to use base classes with hilt?

Comment: Why don't you use the bindings and viewmodels in the activity as is as if without Hilt?  One of the main thrusts of Hilt is to use Android's built-in instance creation as the seams for injection into things like viewmodels

Comment: Since am having multiple activities and fragments I intend to use base classes to reduce redundancy, was using this architecture before with dagger. This is my first build using hilt so am unaware of the limitations.

Comment: I'm asking the same question but with Dagger android. Does someone know?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is not too late but I was able to inject viewModel into base fragment this way:

```
class BaseFragment<T : ViewDataBinding, V: ViewModel>(private val modelClass: Class<V>) : Fragment() {
@Inject
protected lateinit var viewModel: V
}
```

and the usage would be like:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
ScanFragment:BaseFragment<FragmentScanBinding, ScanViewModel>(ScanViewModel::class.java){
```